# Turn a loop into array mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my current code

```
for (let i = 0; i < weatherData.list.length; i += 8) {
    arrTemp.push(
    <div className="display-conditions">
        <p className="display-conditions-item">Location : {weatherData.city.name}, {weatherData.city.country}</p>
        <p className="display-conditions-item">Temperature: {kelvinToCelsius(weatherData.list[i].main.temp)} C</p>
        <p className="weather-condition-container display-conditions-item">
            <img className="img-fluid" alt="icon" src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${weatherData.list[i].weather[0].icon}.png`} />
            Weather Condition: <em>{weatherData.list[i].weather[0].description}</em>
        </p>
        <p className="display-conditions-item">Humidity: {weatherData.list[i].main.humidity}</p>
        <p className="display-conditions-item">Wind Speed: {weatherData.list[i].wind.speed}</p>
    </div>
    )
}
```

This is how I currently use it:

```
weatherDataCondition : res.data.list.map((main,i) => (main))
```

but I want to access it like this:

```
{weatherData.list[i].weather[0].description}
```

Comment: You would simply map like `weatherData.list.map(data => {// JSX here})` where data is `weatherData.list[i]` for each iteration

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to have some better formatting. Formatting is important but the over use of formatting often leads to an unreadable mess. Your `for` was also missing a final `}`